# python how to initiate a value in subclass?

Tags: python, inheritance, subclass, init, args

I have the following code:

```
class Vehicle:
    def __init__(self, name=None, color='Red', make='Toyota'):
        self._name = name 
        self._color = color
        self._make = make

    @property
    def name(self):
        if self._name is None:
            return 'name is none'
        return self._name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, value):
        self._name=value   

    def getColor(self):
        return self._color

    def getMake(self):
        return self._make    

class Car(Vehicle):
    def __init__(self, mode='Running', *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(self,  *args, **kwargs)
        self._mode=mode

    def getMode(self):
        return self._mode
```

I want to initiate the name of the car, however neither of the following works. Is there a simple way to do it?

```
mycar=Car('Corolla')
mycar=Car(name='Corolla')
```

Comment: Please, don't write getters in Python, i.e. `def getColor(self):` etc.

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style, and you don't need those basic getters, this is Python not Java.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not pass `self` into a `super` bound `__init__`

```
class Car(Vehicle):
    def __init__(self, mode='Running', *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```